# Add punctuation at the end of sentence after regular expression processing: Python

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to do some pattern match regular regression problems for my aspect-based sentiment analysis. I can not handle the punctuation in the right position after the pattern match.

```
def extra_expression1(txt):
  txt= str(txt)
  nlp=spacy.load("en_core_web_sm") 
  txt=nlp(txt)
  punc=''
  a=len(txt)
  for token in txt:
    if (token.is_punct==False):
      txt=str(txt)
      txt=re.sub('goo+d+[^a-z]','good',txt) #"goooodddd" to "good"
      a=a-1
    else:
      punc=token.text
      if (a!=0):
        txt=str(txt) + str(punc)
        punc=''
      else:
        txt=str(txt) + str(punc)
      a=a-1
  return txt
```

and

```
txt1=["hotel is goood! breakfast was bad."]
df_22=pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'clean_review' : txt1
    }
)
display(df_22)

for i,txt in enumerate(df_22['clean_review']):
  txt1= extra_expression1(txt)
  df_22['clean_review'].iloc[i]=txt1
df_22
```

the output is(last one after the process):

[image]

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't run your code but the character following `good`  shouldn't be part of the match. Try using lookahead:

```py
txt=re.sub('goo+d+(?=[^a-z])','good',txt) #"goooodddd" to "good"
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked. Can u please tell me the detailed meaning of this "(?=[^a-z])"? It will be helpful for me to understand easily. I know only this [^a-z] part.

Comment: Lookaheads are zero-length assertions. It means they don't consume characters for the match. It allows you to set conditions on the following (or preceding for lookbehind) characters without them being part of the match. Checkout this link: https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html or maybe easier to read: http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html